# Parse.com Friend Relations

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am developing an iOS app that will help people find roommates at the university they attend. I had planned on kind of doing it similar to tinder where you swipe left or right on someone and then if both users swipe right you can start talking. But I am not sure how I would do that in parse because I currently only have one class that holds users and their information. Could anyone possibly help me understand how I would go about do this? Or is there possibly a better way than making both users swipe right to start talking?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating two new tables to capture swipe interactions. Something like:

```
Liked
- initiatingUser
- likedUser

Unliked
- initiatingUser
- unlikedUser
```

And then every time a user swipes right or left, add a new record to the proper table.

Then I would use the AfterSave functionality of Cloud Code to perform a fetch of the Liked table where the initiatingUser and likedUser are flipped. I could then send a push notification to the proper user, create a new record in a new table that both users will see the next time they log in - something along those lines.

Comment: do you have any ideas as to how I could sort through the list for each user, one user at a time allow them to swipe left or right?

Comment: Fetch some amount of users, cache that array on the device, display array[0] to the user, then once they swipe, display array[1], and so on. Once the user has gotten through most of the cached users, fire of the request again and append the newly fetched users to the end of the array.